# Calculate fixed dates for different TimezoneOffset

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetimeoffset

On a specific event, our application needs to queue an email to be sent for all the users at `10:00 AM` their local time.

I know the user TimezoneOffset (-120, 180, 60 etc.), but I don't know how can I calculate the `10:00 AM` of the user relative to the server local time.

```
public void EnqueueNotification()
{
    int[] timezones = new[] { -120, 180, 60 };

    // create the "10:00 AM" for the server
    DateTime serverTime = new DateTime(2021, 02, 18, 10, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
    serverTime = serverTime.AddDays(1);
    // serverTime = "2021-02-19 10:00"

    foreach (int timezone in timezones)
    {
        // at what time of the server is the "10:00 AM" for the timezone ?
        DateTime localDateTime = ???
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet that timezone offset changes throughout the year too.

Comment: I can assume that I always have the correct Timezone offset, regarding daylight saving time.